# AOP can't pointcut class without @Service @Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

AOP can pointcut like @Controller or @Service. 
But it doesn't work well on Class without spring's annotation.

```
package com.erp.module;
@Slf4j
public class SalesOrderModule {
    public void cancel(){
        log.info("test");
    }
    public static SalesOrderModule init(int type) {
        SalesOrderModule salesOrderModule = new SalesOrderModule(salesOrder); 
        *****
        return salesOrderModule;
```

My Aspect.java like below

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class WebLogAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.erp.controller.*.*(..)) || execution(public * com.erp.module.*.*(..))")
    public void logPointCut() {
    }
```

I invoke cancel like below:

```
SalesOrderModule so = SalesOrderModule.init(3);
so.cancel();
```

I know this problem is relative to proxy. But how can I

Comment: As AOP is a part spring architecture so please go through the documentation of spring AOP then only you will understand the inner depth of Spring Aspect-oriented programming- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

Answer (score 3):

[Spring Docs says:](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn)

> Thus, for example, the Spring Framework’s AOP functionality is normally used in conjunction with the Spring IoC container. Aspects are configured using normal bean definition syntax (although this allows powerful "autoproxying" capabilities): this is a crucial difference from other AOP implementations. There are some things you cannot do easily or efficiently with Spring AOP, such as advise very fine-grained objects (such as domain objects typically): AspectJ is the best choice in such cases. However, our experience is that Spring AOP provides an excellent solution to most problems in enterprise Java applications that are amenable to AOP.

So if you need to intercept non-spring managed code, you need to use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. TBH, I didn't need that so far.

Comment: An other question, @Transactional is also not work on method cancel. I consider because this is not in IoC. Thus how can I make transcational work?

Comment: There are plenty of SO questions about @Transactional not working. I would advise to search SO or create separate SO question with code snippets.